# (SSIS) Extracting multiple areas out of a Excel worksheet for DB import

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I want to import a Excel worksheet to a SQL Server database via SSIS.
Within this worksheet there a several areas I need to import to the database table.

For example in A1 I have a string value which needs to go inside an according column of the DB; in F1 to F5 I also have data that I want to import to separate columns for each cell value and then beginning with row A12 to P all the rows till the end should be imported.

The values in A1 and F1:F5 should then spread till the last row entry of A12:P within the DB.

How can I "split" these values in order to export them to the DB? Can this be done with one select statement or is a script-task the only way? I was thinking I could have three Excel sources and maybe combine the output.

For testing purposes I have set-up a variable to select A12:P that I use in the Excel source.

I don't really know where to start with this.

If you have an example (or if you can give one) that deals with this please post it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can always use separate data flow tasks and extract different parts of spreadsheet in each.

Comment: tried that - In my normal dataflow I also insert additional columns which are NOT Null, now I just added a second dataflow to just get the one cell value, which fails because I don't insert values to the not null columns. So I would need a way to insert the data of both dataflows to one row.

Answer (score 1):

got it working with one select statement.

SELECT     [SheetName$A1:A1].F1,...

FROM         [SheetName$A1:A1],....